# Kern Attribute cause Performance slow issue in UITextview

Tags: ios, swift, text, attributes, uitextview

I want to set width of each characters when user typing. I use NSAttributeString with key `.Kern` that works well but when the text length is bigger about 1000+, I touch on screen to place cursor position in front of first line and typing new characters that cause Performance issue, too slow and lag.

```
// Initialize once and reuse every time
lazy var paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
    return paragraphStyle
}()

// Initialize once and reuse every time    
lazy var alignTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = {
    return [
        .kern : 30,
        .paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle,
        .foregroundColor : UIColor.black,
    ]
}()
    
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    // If I want to set each characters with different kern values, how can I do that?
    alignTextAttributes[.kern] = textView.text.count.isMultiple(of: 2) ? 30 : 10

    // This is the key part
    textView.typingAttributes = alignTextAttributes

    // Allow system to control typing
    return true
}
```

Comment: It sounds like a design issue to me.

Comment: @ElTomato what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try -

```
// 4 (or 6 or 8) spaces (depending on font size)
let padding: String = "   "

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    
    var cursorLocation = textView.selectedRange.location
    if text.isEmpty {
        let deleteRange = NSRange(
            location: max(0, range.location - padding.count), 
            length: range.length + padding.count
        )
        textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: deleteRange, with: text)
        cursorLocation -= deleteRange.length
    } 
    else {
        let insertRange = NSRange(
            location: range.location, 
            length: range.length + padding.count
        )
        textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: insertRange, with: text.appending(padding))
        cursorLocation += insertRange.length
    }
    textView.selectedRange.location = cursorLocation
    
    return false
}
```

Comment: thanks but for some reason I can not add padding instead, and set textview cursor  position in this method that cause performance issue . I think you know it in my previous question.